# Regarding the feature generation method with SVM-based classification method

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, svm, text-mining, natural-language

When using SVM to build classifier for a collection of documents, we can use term occurrence, term frequency or even TF/IDF. I would like to know what are the main disadvantages of using term occurrence as the vector generation method?    I once heard that this vector generation method can cause support vector machine to fail.  How to explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the phenomenon you're referring to is more common to hard-margin SVM classification. Using a vector of term occurrences (by which I assume you mean binary feature modeling), you essentially have an n-dimensional feature space (where n is the number of unique features found in your training data, or the number of features in your training data which passed feature selection) in which each dimension has two possible values--zero or one. In hard margin classification, the solution is the linearly-separating hyperplane which correctly divides the two classes in your data. When you have only two possible values the hyperplane can pass through, it is less likely that a solution will exist. Although this can still happen in the soft-margin setting (which allows for a less-than-perfect solution), I've found it to be less common. Don't take this to mean that binary feature modeling is bad! In my research, I'd say it's the most common type of modeling I use, but your mileage may vary according to the characteristics of your data. You might consider trying out kernel transformations (e.g., Radial Basis Function, or RBF) on your feature space, which can transform the space in which your SVM is classifying into one in which a solution may exist!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was told that term occurrence vector, which counts how many words are exists in the document, is kind of worse than binary vector construction within the context of SVM-based classification. But I just cannot build a quantitative relationship between SVM theory and this argument. If you can give some hint, then it will be very helpful.

Comment: I think it really has to do with the characteristics of your data--I'm not sure I'd agree with a blanket statement like "tfidf is always worse than binary" either!